# Greek language in suftesi document class

Tags: languages, characters, greek, thesis

I am trying to create a report using `suftesi` document class. I write my report using both greek and latin characters.

The problem, however, is that I cannot print greek characters. I tried [this](http://ftp.ntua.gr/mirror/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/suftesi/suftesi.pdf) and [this](http://math.sut.ac.th/lab/software/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/suftesi/suftesi.pdf) user guides, but unfortunately I could not solve my problem.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[documentstructure=article,
               greekfont=artemisia,
               defaultgreek,
               tocstyle=dotted]{suftesi}

\usepackage[suftesi]{frontespizio}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}
        This is only an example,but Αυτό είναι μόνο ένα παράδειγμα
\end{document}
```

How can I produce both greek and english characters?

**Edit** I want to compile using `PdfLateX` (I guess, I have to remove both `polyglossia` and `fontspec` package, but after I remove them, I still cannot compile my report).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options `greekfont` and `defaultgreek` are for `pdflatex`, whereas you're apparently using XeLaTeX.

You have to use a font supporting Greek, for instance EBGaramond, as the default font Latin Modern doesn't fully support the Greek alphabet.

```
\documentclass[
  documentstructure=article,
  tocstyle=dotted,
]{suftesi}

\usepackage[suftesi]{frontespizio}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=modern]{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{english}{This is only an example, but} 
Αυτό είναι μόνο ένα παράδειγμα

\end{document}
```

There are several other choices. Remember to keep language changes properly segregated.

[image]

For `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass[
  documentstructure=article,
  tocstyle=dotted,
  greekfont=artemisia,
  defaultgreek,
]{suftesi}

\usepackage[suftesi]{frontespizio}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{english}{This is only an example, but}
Αυτό είναι μόνο ένα παράδειγμα

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem if simply remove the `polyglossia` package and try to complile either with `XeLatex` or `PdfLatex.` I loaded both `polyglossia` and `fontspec` packages because I thought it was necessary for my document class to be compiled.

Comment: @Yorgos I added an example with pdflatex